# A morphism of free modules that is an isomorphism upon dualization.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, free-modules

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $M,N$ be free modules over $R$ and suppose we have a map $f: M \rightarrow N$ such that upon taking $\text{ Hom}(-,R)$ we get an isomorphism $f^* : N^* \rightarrow M^*.$ Must $f$ be an isomorphism as well?

This is clear if $M,N$ are free and of finite dimension, since then double dualization can be applied. But in general, what is true?

**Edit.** In the comments egreg has sketched an example which seems fine. This seems to involve cardinality issues, so what happens if I assume that $M$ and $N$ are both countably generated?

Comment: If you find two cardinal numbers $\alpha<\beta$ with $2^\alpha=2^\beta$, you have a counterexample (take suitable vector spaces over the rationals).   I think this can be proved consistent with ZFC.

Comment: @egreg I believe your example. I edited the question to ask what happens when M and N have bases of the same cardinality.

Comment: If $M$ and $N$ have bases of the same cardinality, they *are* isomorphic.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, but why is $f$ an iso?

Comment: Oh, that's not necessarily true, I guess.

Comment: @Twistediso: I would suggest you accept Jeremy Rickard's answer instead of mine, as his is the correct answer that addresses your question in full generality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}_p$, the $p$-adic integers, and let $M=N$ be countably generated free modules. We can regard elements of $M$ as finite sequences of $p$-adic integers, and elements of $M^*$ as arbitrary sequences of $p$-adic integers.

Let $f$ be the map
$$(a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots)\mapsto(a_0,-pa_0+a_1,-pa_1+a_2,\dots),$$
so that $f^*$ is the map
$$(b_0,b_1,b_2,\dots)\mapsto(b_0-pb_1,b_1-pb_2,b_2-pb_3\dots).$$

Then $f$ is not invertible, since $(1,0,0\dots)$ is not in the image.

But $f^*$ is invertible, with inverse
$$(c_0,c_1,c_2,\dots)\mapsto(c_0+pc_1+p^2c_2+\dots,\text{  }
c_1+pc_2+p^2c_3+\dots,\text{  } c_2+pc_3+p^2c_4+\dots,\text{  }\dots).$$

Comment: By the way, $0\to M\stackrel{f}{\to}M\to\mathbb{Q}_p\to0$ is a $\mathbb{Z}_p$-projective resolution of the $p$-adic rationals, and what I'm actually proving here is that $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}_p}(\mathbb{Q}_p,\mathbb{Z}_p)=0=\text{Ext}^1_{\mathbb{Z}_p}(\mathbb{Q}_p,\mathbb{Z}_p)$.

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out by Jeremy Rickard, this answer is incorrect as originally stated and actually shows only that $f$ is an isomorphism iff $f^*$ is a *topological* isomorphism.  His answer gives an example where $f^*$ is an isomorphism but not a topological isomorphism and so $f$ is not an isomorphism.

---

For any $M$, the dual module $M^*$ can be given the topology of pointwise convergence (that is, the product topology considering $M^*$ as a subset of $R^M$ where $R$ has the discrete topology).  Note furthermore that for any homomorphism $f:M\to N$, the induced homomorphism $f^*:N^*\to M^*$ is continuous.  Finally, I claim that $M$ is the continuous dual of $M^*$ with respect to its topology: that is, every continuous homomorphism $M^*\to R$ is evaluation at an element of $M$.

To prove this, suppose $f:M^*\to R$ is a continuous homomorphism.  Since $f$ is continuous, $\ker(f)$ is an open neighborhood of $0$, which means that there are finitely many elements $x_1,\dots,x_n\in M$ such that for all $\alpha\in M^*$ with $\alpha(x_i)=0$ for $i=1,\dots,n$, $f(\alpha)=0$.  Let $M_0\subseteq M$ be a finitely generated free direct summand of $M$ containing each $x_i$ (for instance, pick a basis for $M$ and let $M_0$ be spanned by all the basis elements which have nonzero coefficient in some $x_i$).  Then $f$ vanishes on the kernel of the restriction map $M^*\to M_0^*$ and thus induces a homomorphism $g:M_0^*\to R$.  Since $M_0$ is finitely generated, $g$ is given by evaluation at some element $x\in M_0$.  It follows that $f$ is also given by evaluation at $x$.

It now follows easily that we can recover $f:M\to N$ from $f^*:N^*\to M^*$ by applying the continuous dual functor.  Thus $f$ is an isomorphism of $R$-modules iff $f^*$ is an isomorphism of topological $R$-modules.  However, beware that $f^*$ may be an isomorphism of $R$-modules without being an isomorphism of topological $R$-modules, since its inverse may not be continuous.  We do get a positive answer in the special case that $R$ is finite, in which case $N^*$ and $M^*$ are compact Hausdorff and so a continuous bijection between them automatically has continuous inverse.

Comment: Bravo and thanks, Eric, for answering this question which really baffled me.

Comment: Awesome answer indeed! It seems to me the argument also works if $R$ is not commutative. (The only change I see is that $M^*$ and $N^*$ become $R^{op}$-modules.) Am I right?

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard: Yes, I believe that's correct.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey:
Thank you for your very elegant answer. I posted a follow-up here: 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2253255/a-module-that-is-free-in-the-profinite-sense-and-double-dual
Inspired by a similar question I had upon reading your answer and thinking whether it generalized to topological rings. Feel free to look at it if you're interested.

Comment: Why does applying the continuous dual functor to $f^*$ give an isomorphism? Must $f^*$ have a continuous inverse?